# Redirect URL while building site

Tags: redirect

Here's what my client wants to do: He wants me to build his wordpress site, but while he's building it, he wants the URL to redirect to his facebook page. I know how to set up the redirect with his domain host, and I know how to set up a wordpress site in maintenance mode, but how do I combine those things--redirecting the URL while still building out the site? Should I build it locally (which is ugh, b/c he wants access while building it), or setting up a sub-domain for the WP site (again ugh but not horrible), or some other idea I am not aware of?

Comment: Sub domain sounds like the best bet there.  I'd recommend having your own environment that you can use a staging server for stuff like this too.  That could even just be subdomains for your own site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me write a plugin for this (save as `wp-content/plugins/red_visitors.php`):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Redirect visitors
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138519
 * Author: still_learning
 */

// function based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/5892694/2948765
// I hope it still works
function __is_login_page() {
    return in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php'));
}

// When WP is ready...
add_action('init', function() {
  // Check what kind of page was requested
  if(!is_user_logged_in() && !__is_login_page() && !is_admin()) {
    // Not logged in, not the login page and not the dashboard
    header("Location: http://your-custom-url.com/foo/bar");
    exit;
  }
});
```

This script *should* redirect every visitor to the specified location (I did not test it). It will obviously fail if you destroy the WordPress installation or make severe programming mistakes causing the PHP interpreter to stop interpreting.

I'd not suggest using the same site for development and production, not even if it's just a redirection. A common approach would be a development server, perhaps accessible over a subdomain (or just a webspace associated with the subdomain), an intra-net server or a local server which can be made available over IPv6.

Comment: This is something I should know the answer to by now, but don't--so if we put it up on dev.<clientURL>.com, and redirect the main URL to facebook, what is the easiest method for 'turning on' the site once everything's done? i.e. migration, change URLs in wordpress settings, etc?

Comment: @MikeEarley That shouldn't be too hard. Read [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) about moving WordPress. If something does not work, a MySQL *search'n'replace* tool is often enough to fix URLs.

Comment: I like this tool for search and replacing on the db, a lot of tools ignore serialization length, which ends up breaking things: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/